# Why Cannot I use Mock and InjectMocks together?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito

valid construction:

```
@InjectMocks
SomeClass sc = mock(SomeClass.class);
```

Invalid construction:

```
@InjectMocks
@Mock
SomeClass sc;
```

I want to inject mocks to another mock. I want to use only annotation style.

Why was in Mockito forbid second construction ?

### Update

**example:**

```
    public class ArrTest {
    private SomeClass someClass;

    public List<String> foo(){
        anotherMethod(); // I suppose that this method works. I want to test it separately.
        //logic which I need to test
        return someClass.doSmth();// I suppose that this method works. I want to test it separately.
    }
    public void anotherMethod(){
        ///...
    }
}
```

---

```
public class SomeClass {
    public List<String> doSmth(){
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

*test*:

```
public class ArrTestTest {
    @InjectMocks
    ArrTest arrTest = Mockito.mock(ArrTest.class);
    @Mock
    SomeClass someClass;
    @Test
    public void fooTest(){        
         Mockito.when(someClass.doSmth()).thenReturn(new ArrayList<String>());
         Mockito.doNothing().when(arrTest).anotherMethod();
         System.out.println(arrTest.foo());
    }

}
```

Comment: By mocking `arrTest`, the implementations of all of its methods and fields become irrelevant. The 'implementation' (and I use the term loosely) is defined by the `Mockito.when().thenReturn()` calls. Mockito can't inject mocks into the `arTest` mock because there are no fields to inject, see answer from @jeff-bowman below. It looks like what you're trying to do is partial mocking, in which case you'd need to create a `@Spy` and/or define the behaviour as `when(mock.someCall().thenCallRealMethod()`.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're trying to do something that doesn't really make sense. You shouldn't *need* to inject any dependencies into your mock since mocks by definition don't have any behaviour until you define it with `when(mock.someMethod()).thenAnswer()` or some variation.

(except perhaps if you're using a `spy()`, but you've specifically said you're using a `@Mock`).

Maybe you could explain your use case and why you're trying to inject dependencies into a mock?

Comment: What if you have to mock a class `A` and `B` which are both injected into class `C` (the System Under Test), meanwhile `B` also needs an injection of `A`. Consider that `A` is some commonly used property/config bag.

Answer (score 1):

[`@InjectMocks`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) specifically indicates that the annotated field will NOT contain a mock. Annotating `@InjectMocks @Mock` is not just unsupported—it's contradictory.

To [return stubs wherever possible](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS), use this:

```
@Mock(answer=Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
YourClass mockYourClassWithDeepStubs;
```

But heed [the official documentation for this Answer](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS):

> **WARNING:** This feature should rarely be required for regular clean code! Leave it for legacy code. Mocking a mock to return a mock, to return a mock, (...), to return something meaningful hints at violation of Law of Demeter or mocking a value object (a well known anti-pattern).
>
> Good quote I've seen one day on the web: **every time a mock returns a mock a fairy dies**.

Answer (score 0):

A mock doesn't have any *real* implementation.  `@InjectMocks` would try to find and call setters for whatever mock objects have already been created and pass them in.  Mockito "knows" that this is kinda pointless on a mock, since there won't be any way to get the mock objects back out, much less do anything meaningful with them.